# How to use d3's zoomable-sunburst

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to use [zoomable suburst](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst) to display some data.  I've generated the json file and am able to use the site to display my data.  Now I'm trying to do this on my local machine, but am not sure of the correct way to go about this.

I think there are a couple of ways of going about this.  One would be to just dump the js code into a js file and import it into an html file.  I've seen some implementations on github give me the ability to do this, but they are not as clean as the one i've found on observablehq.  And I'm unable to get the one on observablehq to work locally doing a copy/paste.

I also see an option on observablehq where i can download the code.  I did that and the readme that came with it says that i need to run it on a server (ex. `python -m http.server`), but when i run the server from the folder containing the downloaded code, i keep getting a bunch of

> code 404, message File not found

Now I'm a bit confused. I'd like to know the "right" way to go about using zoomable sunburst to show my data, and if it's at all possible to run this on my local.

Any suggestions/advice would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about what your are looking for, do you mean you are not able to get the source code for the example on observable? or do you have errors running the code your local?

Comment: I’m unable to run my downloaded source which makes me wonder if I’ve grabbed it in the correct manner. So both really.

Answer (score 0):

I'm super late to the party, but here is what was the problem for me :

I was running `python -m http.server` in the wrong directory, i.e the directory that didn't have `index.html` file inside. on I ran it in the directory that had the `index.html` file it worked perfectly.

hope this helps someone!